# Checkbox not being sent in POST using PHP

Tags: php, html, smarty

I have a checkbox and it is not being sent to the call back page using POST. I've read that it needs a value, and I supplied that, but am not sure what else could be wrong. Here's the checkbox code I am currently using. Smarty is being used here.

```
{foreach from=$all_splash_carriers item=item}
            <tr>
                    <td class="evp">{$item.carrier}:</td>
                    <td><input name="{$item.splash_carriers_id}.splashcarrier.{$item.carrier_id}" value="{$item.url}"/><input type="checkbox"  name="{$item.carrier_id}.checkbox" value="1" {if $item.activated == '1'}checked{/if}/>Activated</td>

            <tr>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: there's some unnamed framework in use here

Comment: it's [smarty](http://www.smarty.net)

Comment: ah ok, kind of an important thing to mention in the question.

Comment: @Reid nothing seems wrong with your code. Only reason of checkbox not preselecting is `{$item.activated == '1'}` failing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The checkbox is not sent if it is not checked.

Also, PHP silently converts any dots in names to underscores, because otherwise the "register_globals" mode would render inaccessible global variables.

Comment: I have tried checking the box, but it still is not getting sent.

Comment: This answer helped me find the problem. The item was being sent, but the name was being sent as 1_checkbox not 1checkbox as I expected.

Comment: Right, because PHP silently converts any dots in names to underscores, because otherwise the "register_globals" mode would render inaccessible global variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
if $item.activated == '1'
```

should be

```
if ($item.activated == '1')
```

Comment: this doesn't matter in smarty for single binary condition.