# Adding multiple checkbox items to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php/mysql and I am learning quite a bit. I have hit a snag with my checkboxes.
I have looked and everything I have come across is not making sense to me.

Pretty much I am doing a site where the admin can add a user and there are checkboxes that will say what the user is interested in. (more than one can be selected.

Example
Interested in what sports. (these are checkboxes users can select)

- Baseball
- Football
- Hockey

and so on

How can I have it where the choices are stored in the database?

Here is what I have so far.

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-8">
<label style="margin-right:10px; width:130px"><input name="interested[]" type="checkbox" value="a6"><span class="cats">Baseball</span></label>
<label style="margin-right:10px; width:130px"><input name="interested[]" type="checkbox" value="a6"><span class="cats">Football</span></label>
<label style="margin-right:10px; width:130px"><input name="interested[]" type="checkbox" value="a6"><span class="cats">Hockey</span></label>
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set("display_errors", 1);

// Pick up the form data and assign it to variables
$id = @$_POST['id'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$altemail = $_POST['altemail'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$home = $_POST['home'];
$cell = $_POST['cell'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$category = $_POST['category']; 
$usertype = $_POST['usertype']; 
$assigned = $_POST['assigned']; 
$othercat = $_POST['othercat']; 
$interested=$_POST['interested'];



//Get data in local variable

$id = @$_POST['id'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$altemail = $_POST['altemail'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$home = $_POST['home'];
$cell = $_POST['cell'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$category = $_POST['category']; 
$usertype = $_POST['usertype'];
$assigned = $_POST['assigned']; 
$othercat = $_POST['othercat'];     
$interested=$_POST['interested'];

// You have to loop through the array of checked box values ...
$interested="";
foreach($interested as $entry){
$interested .= $entry.",";
}


if ($fname=="" || $email=="")
{
echo "All fields must be entered, hit back button and re-enter information";
}else{



$query="INSERT INTO users(`id`, `fname`, `lname`, `email`, `notes`,`company`,`address`,`cell`,`home`,`telephone`,`category`,`usertype`,`assigned`,`altemail`,`othercat`,`interested`) VALUES('$id','$fname','$lname','$email','$notes','$company','$address','$telephone','$category','$usertype','$assigned','$altemail','$othercat','$cell','$home','$interested')";
```

Like I mentioned, I am brand new to PHP/Mysql. I have only been doing it for about 8 days now. I have come quite a ways with it but this has me stumped.

Any help would be appreciated. Not trying to put myself down, but with all the others that I have looked at and no being able to grasp, please kind of dumb it down for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checkbox not being sent in POST using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753677/checkbox-not-being-sent-in-post-using-php) and/or [how-come-checkbox-state-is-not-always-passed-along-to-php-script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520952/how-come-checkbox-state-is-not-always-passed-along-to-php-script)

Comment: your should have an interest table joining user_id to intererst_id

Comment: its a good time to start learning some basics such asalways sanitising user input